# wordpress plugin woocommerce display all products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display all products in product category pages.
I already all category about products. I want to click category name, display its all product and cutcover current pages. Other category also same.

My `archive-product.php code`:

```
<dl class="archive-cat">
<?php 
    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
        echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );   
    }
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'hierarchical' => 0, 
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'exclude' => 1 
    );

    $all_categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
        /* if ($cat->category_parent == 0)
        {
            $category_lists[$cat->term_id] = $cat->name;
            //get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat')
        } */
        if( get_the_ID() === $cat->term_id) {

            echo '<dt class="z-current" data-name="' .$cat->slug. '">'; 
        } else {

            echo '<dt data-name="' .$cat->slug. '">'; 
        }
        echo $cat -> name;
        echo '</dt>';
    }
?>
</dl>

<?php


if ( have_posts() ) {

 /**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
 *
 * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
 * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
woocommerce_product_loop_start();

if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {

    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();


        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
         *
         * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }
}

woocommerce_product_loop_end();

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
 */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
} else {
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
 *
 * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
 */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}
```

I can't display all product. Please help me, thank you very much.
My products don't click it.

Comment: Time to do some reading on functions such as wc_get_products() 
 https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

Comment: I am not able to understand what you have tried to achieve. Please edit your question with a bit refined English.